# What is the "select when" syntax for?

Tags: crystal-lang

Experimenting with the language I've found that `select` is defined in the global scope and its precedence is higher than local variables.

```
def example(select)
  puts select
end
example 3
# Syntax error in eval:3: unexpected token: end (expecting when, else or end)
```

So experimenting with select step by step I get this:

```
select 1 end
# Syntax error in eval:3: unexpected token: end (expecting when, else or end)
```

and then

```
select when 1 end
# Syntax error in eval:1: invalid select when expression: must be an assignment or call
```

then

```
select when x = 1 end
# Syntax error in eval:1: invalid select when expression: must be an assignment or call
```

then

```
select when x
# Syntax error in eval:1: unexpected token: EOF (expecting ',', ';' or '
```

I'll skip ahead a few steps as you should have an idea of how I've come to my question…

```
select when x;
else y
end
# Error in line 1: undefined local variable or method 'x_select_action'
```

and lastly

```
x_select_action = 4

select when x;
else y
end
# Error in line 3: undefined method 'x_select_action' (If you declared 'x_select_action' in a suffix if, declare it in a regular if for this to work. If the variable was declared in a macro it's not visible outside it)
```

So there is this keyword in the language which precedes local variables precedence and I don't know what it's for.  But apparently it looks for `x_select_action` when `x` is given as a when clause.  What is this `select` for and how is it meant to be used?

Searching online I see `select` defined on Enumerable, Hash, Channel, and Array… but at first glance these don't seem to be it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to Go's select: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

But it still needs some tweaks to be finished, that's why there are no docs about it yet.

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a PR on this feature?